# How to write a JSDoc code to prevent unwanted property to be added into an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, jsdoc, jsdoc3

```js
    /**
     * @typedef {object} User
     * @property {number} id
     * @property {string} name
     */

    /**@type {User} */
    let user

    user.phoneNo = '123456'  // Should give an Error
```

if not with jsDoc itself, is there any plugin that can achieve this

> I know it can be achieved with ts easily

adding un-defined properties(jsDoc) to object should return an error

Comment: JSDoc is simply a documentation tool. However, some IDEs (such as Visual Studio Code) use it to power TypeScript behind the scenes in order to improve developer experience though things like autocompletion. If you would like your IDE to give you an error if you break type rules, then you should look into [learning TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html)